# How to a run a php script in the background without causing the browser to show a loading animation?

Tags: php, linux, bash

I have two php scripts

**sleep.php**

```
<?php sleep(5); ?>
```

**sleep_from_shell.php**

```
<?php shell_exec("php sleep.php &"); ?>
```

When I access `mysite.com/sleep_from_shell.php` the browser tab title is labeled 'Connecting...' and displays a little loading animation for 5 seconds.  In other words `sleep_from_shell.php` is behaving the same way it would if the code was `<?php shell_exec("php sleep.php"); ?>` (no ampersand &)

[image]

I executed `php sleep.php &` from the command line and the terminal didn't hang so I was wondering if it was possible to do the same from the cgi.

## EDIT

My goal is to access `mysite.com/sleep_from_shell.php` and have the tab load immediately without having the tab title say 'Connecting...', thus `sleep.php` is running in the background.  Is this possible?

Comment: I can't really tell what you're asking but you may want to check out [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)

Comment: I just edited my original post, see for clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in `sleep_from_shell.php` has to be

```
<?php shell_exec("php sleep.php > log.txt &"); ?>
```

Instead of

```
<?php shell_exec("php sleep.php &"); ?>
```

You need to include a file to pipe the stdout to even though there is no stdout or else the browser window will hang for 5 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

try to add `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` because webbrowser automatically cut the loading after some time if this isn't set.

EDIT :

Now you provided your goal, it is possible with ajax. I let you do some research about ajax. When you will write your ajax, think about setting a long timeout :)

Comment: Pretty sure this will just kill the script without the external process running.

Answer (score -1):

The "&" in the command means put the process started to background, so the command execution didn't wait for the process finish before return. That's why it didn't hang.

Comment: I know this... I don't think you understood my question.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this in the first line:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
```